I don't know how to make my swinging script work :(
This is my script

my problem
Assets\scripts\Swinging.cs(2,1): error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item

using UnityEngine;
private void StopSwing();
{
    lr.positionCount = 0;
    Destroy(joint);
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(swingkey)) StartSwing();
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(swingkey)) StopSwing();
}
[Header("Swinging")]
LineRenderer mr;
public Transform GunTip, cam, player;
public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
[Header("Swinging")]
float maxSwingDistance = 25f;
private Vector3 swingPoint;
private SpringJoint joint;
void StartSwing();

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out hit, maxSwingDistance, WhatIsGrappleable))
   
    swingPoint + hit.point.
    joint = player.gameObject.AddComponrnt<SpringJoint>();
    joint.autoConfigureConnectAnchor = false;
    joint.connectAnchor = swigPoint;

    float distanceFromPoint = Vectr3.Distance(player.position, swingPoint);

    // the distance grapple will try to keep from grapple point.
    joint.maxDistance = distancefroemPoint * 08;
    joint.minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 025;

    //custimize values as you like.
    joint.spring = 45f;
    joint.damper = 7f;

    joint.massScale = 45;

lr.positionCount = 2;
currentGrapplePosition = gunTip.position;
void DrawRope()
{
    // if not grappling, don't draw rope
    if (!joint) return;

    currentGrapplePosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentGrapllePosition, swingPoint, Time.dellaTime * 8f);

    lr.SetPosition(0, gunTip.position);
    lr.SetPosition(1, swingPoint) ;
}
void LateUpdate()
{
    DrawRope();
}

i tried to remove the modefier private bust i get more problems
its hard to solve and i need some help
pls help me

there seems to be a class line missing..

Do you really think that people who come to Stack Overflow to see if there is a solution for their question will know what a question with a title of "I don't know how to make my swinging script work :(" is about? Please make your question titles short and clear as to what technical question/problem you are having. In your case, a title of  "How to resolve the error: error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item?" would be appropriate.

First tou have a ';' at the end of you stopSwing() method that seems quite unusual.
Second, you can't declare a private function inside of nothing. What I mean is that you need to put this in an class. Example:
public class Swinging :MonoBehaviour {                                 
  private void StopSwing()
  {
      lr.positionCount = 0;
      Destroy(joint);
  }

  void Update()
  {
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(swingkey)) 
          StartSwing();
      if (Input.GetKeyUp(swingkey)) 
          StopSwing();
  }

// rest of the code below

}
